# req.body is returning object but object comes out to be undefined in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

The code Combines expressjs NodeJs and Mongodb

When I console log req.body it comes out to be
[object Object]
but when I console log req.body.name it comes out to be undefined.I am sending data through POST method like this through POSTMAN
{
"name":"vaibhav",
"tech":"NodeJS",
}

my program is this
app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Alien';

mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true});
const conn = mongoose.connection;    //handle of db
conn.on("open", function(){
    console.log('connected....');
})
app.use(express.json())


const alienRouter = require("./routers/aliens");
app.use('/alien', alienRouter);




app.listen(9000, (err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log("error in starting server")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Listening on port 9000")
    }
})
```

router/alien.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Alien = require("../models/alien")

router.get("/", async(req, res)=>{
    try{
        const aliens = await Alien.find()
        res.json(aliens)
    }
    catch(err){
        res.send("Error" + err)
    }
})

router.get("/:id", async(req, res)=>{
    try{
        const aliens = await Alien.findById(req.params.id)
        res.json(aliens)
    }
    catch(err){
        res.send("Error" + err)
    }
})

//POST METHOD
router.post("/", async(req, res)=>{
    console.log("body "+req.body);
    const alien = new Alien({
        name: req.body.name,
        tech: req.body.tech,
        sub: req.body.sub
    })

    try{
        const al = await alien.save();
        res.json(al);
    }catch(err){
        res.send("Error: "+err)
    }
    
})

module.exports = router;
```

model/alien.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const alienSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
    },
    tech:{
        type:String,
        reqired:true
    },
    sub:{
        type:Boolean,
        required:true,
        default:false
    }

})

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Alien', alienSchema);
```

can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Remove `app.use(bodyparser.json());`.  You only want one middleware per type, not two and there's no reason to use body-parser any more as it's all built-into Express now.  Are you 100% sure the incoming data is `application/json`?  Can you show the client code that creates the request?

Comment: .I am sending data through POST method through POSTMAN and this is only form of incoming data currentlym,      { "name":"vaibhav", "tech":"NodeJS", }

Comment: That still doesn't tell us exactly what the content-type is for the incoming request.  You could add `console.log(req.headers)` and see exactly what the `content-type` is set to.  Then, also do `console.log(req.body)` and see if there's anything in it.

Comment: when i console.log(req.body) it returns [object Object] and same for console.log(req.headers)

Comment: Uhhh, `console.log(req.body)` doesn't do `[object Object]` unless you somehow replaced the logging system so you must be doing the logging differently.  Please use the EXACT code I suggested to log it.  If you're trying to label the logs, then do it this way" `console.log("body", req.body)`, NOT this way `console.log("body " + req.body)`.

Comment: What you show in the post method is precisely WRONG.  Do it the way I suggest in my previous comment.

Comment: this is body -> {}

Comment: So, your postman request is sending `text/plain`, not `application/json`.  You need to fix the postman request to send JSON.  That's why the json middleware is not doing anything.

Comment: thanks got it i was sending text/plain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POSTMAN request is sending `text/plain` instead of `application/json`.  That is why your `express.json()` middleware is not parsing the request and putting data into `req.body`.

You need to fix your POSTMAN request so that it formats the data as JSON and sends the right content-type.

Answer (score 2):

In the Postman, select Body->raw (JSON application/json from dropdown) and send your data in json format

```
{
    "name": "Your Name",
    "tech": "Your Tech",
    "sub": "Your Subject"
}
```